# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning for pg.Pool promise chaining

Tags: javascript, postgresql, promise

My promise returns the expected database query from the first `.then` statement, but the second `.then` in the chain fails with `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined`. As far as I can tell, `client` is defined and each promise has a valid `.catch`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const pool = new pg.Pool(config.db);

pool.connect()
  .then(client => {
    return client.query('SELECT * FROM staffers WHERE id=800')
      .then(res => {
        client.release();
        console.log(res.rows[0]);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Error executing first psql query', err.stack));
  })
  .then(client => {
    return client.query('UPDATE staffers SET num_times_tweeted=num_times_tweeted + 1 WHERE id=800')
      .then(res => {
        client.release();
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Error executing second psql query', err.stack));
  })
  .catch(err => {
  client.release();
  console.error('Error acquiring client: ', err.stack);
});

// pool shutdown
pool.end();
```

The specific error I get is as follows:

```
(node:44233) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at pool.connect.then.then.catch.err (/Users/danielmiller/.../.../app.js:...)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:44233) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:44233) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**EDIT**
Based on Chris's suggestion I was able to get the promise works by returning the `client` from each `.then` statement. I don't understand why this works though? Also calling `client.release();` within `finally` doesn't seem to actually release `client`?

```
pool.connect()

    .then(client => {
        return client.query('SELECT * FROM staffers WHERE id=800')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.rows[0]);
                return client;
            })
            .catch(err => console.error('Error executing first psql query', err.stack));
    })

    .then(client => {
        return client.query('UPDATE staffers SET num_times_tweeted=num_times_tweeted + 1 WHERE id=800')
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                return client;
            })
            .catch(err => console.error('Error executing second psql query', err.stack));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        client.release();
        console.error('Error acquiring client: ', err.stack);
    })
    .finally(() => {
        client.release();
        // pool shutdown
        pool.end();
    });
```

Comment: You really only need one query there: `UPDATE staffer SET num_times_tweeted=num_times_tweeted+1 WHERE id=800;`. There's no good reason to select, particularly where you don't seem to be doing anything with the selected row data.

I think you need to `return client;` from your then to alleviate your error. I also think the `pool.end()` should go inside a `finally()` block.

Comment: The `SELECT` is a stand in for some other logical I'll write later. Basically conditionally evaluating various rows from the database, and then the `UPDATE` needs to happen after that. It doesn't work to do `client.query` more than once within a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it something like this:

```
const pool = new pg.Pool(config.db);

let pgClient = null;

pool.connect()
.then(client => {
    // Assign client so we don't need to pass it around
    pgClient = client;
    return pgClient.query('SELECT * FROM staffers WHERE id=800')
    .then(res => {
        // Note, no .release() because we still want to use the client,
        // and that's now handled in the finally block.
        console.log(res.rows[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error('Error executing first psql query', err.stack));
})
.then(() => {
    return pgClient.query('UPDATE staffers SET num_times_tweeted=num_times_tweeted + 1 WHERE id=800')
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => console.error('Error executing second psql query', err.stack));
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('Error acquiring client: ', err.stack);
})
.finally(() => {
    // Release client to pool
    if (pgClient) {
        pgClient.release();
    }
    // pool shutdown
    pool.end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I added my attempt above before I saw your answer here. So you use a globally-scoped variable `pgClient` so that it can be released in `finally` based on the results of the callbacks? What is the advantage to doing it this way versus my attempt above?

Comment: I missed that. Your way would also work. I'm just an old C programmer that had to learn node.js a while back (0.10.25 days) and that's the sort of paradigm I always used in instances like this. :)